# 2 Linked Servers using MSDASQL with conflicting Provider settings

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked server problem on a SQL Server 2012 database.

Linked Server 1 accesses a sql server 2000 database using sql server native client 10.0 and MSDASQL provider.

Linked Server 2 accesses a mysql database using mysql odbc 5.1 driver and MSDASQL provider.

If Level Zero Only is unchecked on the MSDASQL provider Linked Server 1 works but Linked Server 2 does not ("An invalid schema or catalog was specified for the provider “MSDASQL” for linked server").

If Level Zero Only is checked on MSDAQL provider Linked Server 1 does not work (error as above) but Linked Server 2 does.

Is there a way to provide the value of Level Zero Only on the provider string in the linked server settings? Or can anyone explain why this scenario is happening and how to fix it. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

couldn't figure it out so I just solved it using openquery instead of selecting from linked server! not great but time constraints needed it solved.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I also had this problem when linking servers to SQLServer from POSTGRES and MYSQL , so I just uncheck the checkbox 'level zero Only', because I read that it's not a good practice have it enabled.

https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/9955/what-options-for-a-ms-sql-server-linked-server-provider-does-the-sa-oledb-provider-support

To solve it i just unchecked and to query data to MYSQL i just `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (yourLinkedServerName, 'yourQuery')` and this will do the trick

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16